# How to test if an alert message is showing what I wanted it to show using Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have password reset page I'd like to perform some tests on. If my current password won't match with my typed current password area it shows a "Password don't match" alert. Here is my alert:

```js
<p-message *ngIf="error" severity="error" id="alert-danger" class="alert alert-danger"  text="{{'password.messages.error' | translate}}" >
    <ng-template pTemplate>
         <div jhiTranslate="password.messages.error" ></div>
    </ng-template>
 </p-message>
```

What I've tried so far:

```js
cy.get('[severity="error"] > .p-inline-message > .p-inline-message-text')
  .should("have.text","password.messages.error")
```

But I get an error in cypress saying "expected **password.messages.error** but the text was **Passwords don't match!**. Which is understandable it takes directly whatever text was inside my element. Then I've tried:

```js
cy.get('[severity="error"] > .p-inline-message > .p-inline-message-text')
  .invoke('attr','jhiTranslate')
  .should('eq','password.messages.error')
```

this gives me "expected **undefined** to equal **password.messages.error**"

What I'm doing wrong and what else should I try here?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the text Cypress is checking,

```js
cy.get('[severity="error"] > .p-inline-message > .p-inline-message-text')
  .should("have.text", "Passwords don't match!")
```

The HTML you show above is the source code, but AngularJS has looked up the variable `password.messages.error` and output the string contained in that variable.

It then removes `jhiTranslate` from the element, so you cannot test it at runtime (in the browser).

You can see what the runtime HTML is by right-clicking on an element and inspecting it in the dev-tools.

Comment: This works for me as well but only for single language. I have several languages compatible for this website. That's why I have passwords.messages.error translated into those languages.

Comment: As a tester, if you are testing multiple languages, then each test should be designed to handle a particular language. You cannot rely on the content of a variable, because a bug in the code may cause `password.messages.error` to have the English text when the global language is set to something else.

Comment: I've began testing only for 2 weeks. Excuse my inexperince and thanks for the tip I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```js
cy.get('p-message#alert-danger').within(() => {
  cy.get('div').should('have.attr', 'jhiTranslate', 'password.messages.error')
})
```

Comment: for some reason I'm getting 'div expected to have attribute jhiTranslate' and I guess can't seem to find it. I've tried using this with "cy.get('ng-template').should....." but got the same type of error.

Comment: The above code should work as per the html. If this is not working, please check your HTML.